# border-box making button pushed halfway down input

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/Xnbf4/

When enabling border-box my button is pushed half way down the input. Removing the padding from the input "fixes" it but obviously not a real fix...

The button and input should be inline (not a gap above the button).

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.input {
display: inline-block;
margin: 5px;
border: 2px solid $web-lines;
padding: 15px;
height: 18px;
}

.input-search {
padding: 15px 25px;
}

.button { /*Default button */
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin: 5px;
border: 0;
border-bottom: 3px solid $web-green-darker;
padding: 7px 15px 5px 15px;
color: #fff;
font-weight: 600;
background: #4d913e;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: The button and input should be inline (not a gap above the button). Much more noticeable in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `vertical-align: middle`: http://jsfiddle.net/Xnbf4/6/

```
.button, .input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Vertical align works with any `inline` elements, including `inline-block`. I'm not sure what the initial property is set to (it doesn't seem to have one), but not setting it seems to cause an issue. If anyone has more information, hopefully they will chime in.

Comment: This is great. Are you able to explain a little why this is required? I thought this was a table cell only thing?

Comment: I just updated with a little information, but I don't know a lot of the specifics.